# Display image in a "fullscreen" view - when image view has been tapped

Tags: ios, interface-builder, segue

In [a simple test app for iPhone](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyPhone) I display (using SDWebImage) a user avatar on the top:

[image: app screenshot]

When the app user taps the avatar I'd like to display that picture "fullscreen" in another view.

So I have added that view to my Xcode 5 storyboard and also tap recognizer and the push segue which I've called "pushZoom" (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hRZG.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

The tap recognizer works okay, I can see its method being called.

**My question:** is there maybe a simple way in Interface Builder to pass the image to the new view or do I have to go the tedious way (add ZoomViewContoller.[mh] files, define an outlet for the image view there)?

Below is the copy of my [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyPhone/MyPhone/ViewController.m) in case I modify it later @ GitHub:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

static NSString* const kAppleMaps = @"https://maps.apple.com/?q=%@";
static NSString* const kGoogleMaps = @"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?q=%@&x-success=myphone://?resume=true&x-source=MyPhone";
static NSString* const kAvatar = @"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6Uce9r3S9D8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAC5I/ZZo0yzCajig/photo.jpg";

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setTitle:@"Google+"];

    _firstName.text = @"Alex";

    [_cityBtn setTitle:@"Bochum" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Male.png"]];
}

- (IBAction)avatarTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (IBAction)cityPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSURL* testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
    NSString* fmt = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:testURL] ? kGoogleMaps : kAppleMaps);
    NSString* city = [self urlencode:_cityBtn.currentTitle];
    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, city];
    NSLog(@"%s: city=%@ str=%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, city, str);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}

- (NSString*)urlencode:(NSString*)str
{
    return (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
        NULL,
        (__bridge CFStringRef) str,
        NULL,
        CFSTR(":/?@!$&'()*+,;="),
        kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need another viewController. You may keep an imageView of full size over you view without any image initially and keep it hidden, and on tapping that button, remove it from hiding. and just pass the image. So it doesn't need any of these problems. It seems simple for me

Answer (score 1):

In my experience is small , but I show my idea

```
- (IBAction)avatarTapped:(id)sender {

   //here use your choice in singleton or NSUserdefaults for passing the image url from one VC to another VC. here I used NSUserdefaults

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:kAvatar forKey:@"userimage"];
}
```

in your full image show ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *userimg =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"userimage"];

 [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userimg]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Male.png"]];
}
```

Comment: any changes i waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Pass image URL as string or url  to next screen and show it in an imageView using

```
[self.myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];
```

Thats what i would do.Please post here if you got some better idea.